# How do I get first x elements of an NSArray in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

New to Cocoa, and seem to be missing something.

What is the most elegant/idiomatic way to obtain the first x elements of an `NSArray` as another `NSArray`?  Obviously I can iterate through them and store them manually, but it seems like there has to be a more standard method of doing this.

I was expecting there to be an `-arrayWithObjectsInRange:` or something similar, but don't see anything...

```
NSArray* largeArray...// Contains 50 items...

NSArray* smallArray = // fill in the blank     

// smallArray contains first 10 items from largeArray
```

Thanks!

Comment: For anyone who is trying to do the same thing, but starting with an unknown size array, I've asked a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928973/how-do-i-get-the-first-x-elements-of-an-unknown-size-nsarray

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can use [`subarrayWithRange:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/subarrayWithRange:).

```
NSArray *smallArray = [largeArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, MIN(10, largeArray.count))];//MIN() used because array must be larger than or equal to range size, else exception will be thrown
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be NSMakeRange(0,9)?

Comment: @SeptiadiAgus: `NSRange` has the format `{starting index, length}`, so if you want the first 10 elements, the second argument is `10`.

Comment: Keep in mind, if largeArray does not have x items program will crash.

Comment: for some reason I can't specify a range within an array say the 10th element to the 15th element, `NSLog(@"%i", [[self.allObjects subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(self.cellCount, self.cellCount+5)] count]);`
What is wrong?

Comment: To avoid `NSRangeException` for less than 10 elements you should use: `[largeArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, MAX(10, largeArray.count)]`

Comment: Thanks @Harry. Should be MIN(10, largeArray.count)

Comment: @Szu I've edited this into the original answer with //comments, as I think this is a crucial thing that may go un-noticed in comment section

Answer (score 22):

```
firstNItems = [items subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, MIN(n, items.count))];
```

Answer (score 0):

2nd parameter is number of array items to include in the range, not the 'to' index

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3 you can use this:

```
let smallArray = largeArray.prefix(10)
```

Comment: question asks for objective c