# How do I get the first X elements of an unknown size NSArray?

Tags: objective-c

In objectiveC I have an NSArray, let's call it `NSArray* largeArray`, and I want to get a new `NSArray* smallArray` with just the first x objects

...OR in the event that largeArray is already size <= x I just want a copy of the largeArray. So truncating any objects after index x.

This approach:

```
NSArray *smallArray = [largeArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, x)];
```

Was the answer to [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364758/how-do-i-get-first-x-elements-of-an-nsarray-in-cocoa). But it fails with an error if largeArray is already small.

Comment: It's always cheap to obtain the size of an array. Maybe you want to avoid creating the large array in the first place? (Like, when reading lines from a file, to stop after reading a maximum of 100 lines.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could do this...

```
NSArray *smallArray = [largeArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, MIN(x, largeArray.count))];
```

That will take the first x elements or the full array if it's smaller than x.

If largeArray.count is 100.

If x = 110 then it will take the first 100 results.
If x = 90 then it will take the first 90 results.

Yep, that works :D

Comment: OK, this will work now. You can't just take MAX or MIN. You need a bit more logic.

Comment: Why not use `NSMakeRange(0, MIN(x, largeArray.count))`?

Comment: Because I was being an idiot. I put MAX in the answer and thought it wasn't right. Then for some reason I ruled out MIN too... LOL! Edited :D

Comment: This is an awesome solution, but you left out a close parenthesis in the solution!

Comment: Also, the "A" in "subArrayWithRange" should not be capitalized.

Finally, shouldn't "largeArray.count" be "largeArray.count-1" to makeup the difference between and index starting at zero and a count starting at 1?

Comment: I've made the changes thanks. @Amos NSRange is created using a start location and length. Not an end location. So using count is correct in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Fogmeister's answer is perfectly good, but, in situations where the array is often already small enough, that answer will be mildly inefficient since it always makes a copy.  Here is a more efficient version:

```
NSAarray *smallArray = largeArray;
if (smallArray.count > MAX_NUM_ITEMS)
    smallArray = [smallArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, MAX_NUM_ITEMS)];
```

When the array is already within the limit this version will just make a reference to the existing array.

Answer (score -5):

Here's the obvious long-hand way of doing it:

```
NSMutableArray* smallMutableArray;
if ([largeArray count] <= x) {
    smallMutableArray = [largeArray copy];
} else {
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
       [smallMutableArray addObject:[largeArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

Comment: As smallArray is an NSArray (as you've stated in the question) you can't add objects to it because it's immutable.

Comment: fine OK. Let's call it smallMutableArray.  It isn't elegant I know. That's why I was asking :-)

Comment: Several issues in this snippet: 1. `copy` creates immutable array. 2. `smallMutableArray` will never be initialized in `else` case. 3. No need to create subarray by hand. 4. No need to copy when array is short.