# How to show first 50 name from an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

My array contains more than 100 names and I just want to show the first 50 array.

I have read this topic ([How do I get first x elements of an NSArray in Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364758/how-do-i-get-first-x-elements-of-an-nsarray-in-cocoa)) but is there a better solution instead of adding two arrays?

I'm adding the array like this

```
-(void)test{
     _myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [_myArray addObject:usersName];
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `subarrayWithRange:` like suggested in that answer?

Comment: the accepted answer there is probably the most efficient way, its only one new array with pointers to the same objects

Comment: Show the names *where*?

Comment: @Popeye I was looking for a way in limiting the array instead of creating another array. Which could be more efficient thats all.

Comment: Show how you are using the array.

Comment: Like has been said the accepted answer on that question is probably the most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: @Popeye What if the OP is using the array as the datasource for a tableview; there is no need to touch the array at all then?

Comment: @Popeye  I didn't know that because it is an old question. Thanks for your help. While I want to limit it for my `tableView`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to limit how much of the array can be seen within a tableview, where the array is the datasource of the tableview, then you just need to use the `MIN` macro with the tableview datasource 
`- tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return MIN([_array count], 50);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That what I was going to use it for.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use [subarrayWithRange:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/subarrayWithRange:)