# What's the NSPredicate syntax for limiting data?

Tags: ios, cocoa, camera, photolibrary

What's the syntax for limiting data, in my case, the number of photos fetched from iPod's photo library?

Is it 'first' x objects, or something?

I have a lot of photos and I would like to limit them to a few.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get first x elements of an NSArray in Cocoa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364758/how-do-i-get-first-x-elements-of-an-nsarray-in-cocoa)

Comment: I'm referring to a fetch from a database/data-source; not from an array.